# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in file.php on line 111

Tags: php, html

I am currently getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in file.php on line 111 when I run my file.php.

Below is the code that is being affected.

```
<?php
  if(user_logged_in() || validate_user()[user_role] == 'administrator') {
?>
<body>
    <div class="chart" id="OrgChart"></div>
</body>
<?php
  } else {
      echo '<p>Error: You need to be an Admin</p>';
  }
?>
```

Can anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: What is `validate_user()` doing? What does that function do?

Comment: @Qirel validate_user() is a function that returns an associate array holding 'user_role' and 'user_login' information. I have fixed the problem creating a new variable $tmp=validate_user(); and <?php
  if(user_logged_in() || $tmp[user_role] == 'administrator') {
?>

Comment: Can you show that function in your question?

Comment: And what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: PHP 5.3. I think that might be the reason. Many thanks @Qirel